# Plotly.js - How do I make two y-axes associated with a single x-axis?

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

How do I make two y-axes associated with a single x-axis? In the image we see that each y-axis has its own x-axis. I already used anchor = 'x' in the yaxis2 layout, but nothing has changed.

[image: Gráfico com problema]

Below the layout used:

```
var layout = {
    title: 'Coeficientes',
    showlegend: true,
    legend: {
        "orientation": "h"
    },
    width: 800,
    height: 580,
    autosize: true,
    margin: {
        l: 50, r: 70, b: 50, t: 50, pad: 2
    },
    xaxis: {title: 'Ângulo [graus]'},
    yaxis: {title: '[kN/(m/s)²]'},
    yaxis2 = {
        title: '[kN.m/(m/s)²]',
        overlaying: 'y',
        side: 'right'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try with set `xaxis` and `yaxis` value of each trace. It's works

```
 var trace1 = {
      x:x,
      y:y1,
      type:'scatter',
      xaxis:'x',
      yaxis:'y'
    }
    var trace2 = {
      x:x,
      y:y2,
      type:'scatter',
      xaxis:'x',
      yaxis:'y2'
    }
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/mdnasirfardoush/pen/WyMMdg?editors=1010)

> Sometimes grid line not adjusted. it's happens when different `yaxis`
>   range is different.
>   So we can overcome this issue with set of same `range` each y-axis

```
 var Yvalues = y1.concat(y2); // Merge y values
 var yMax = Math.max.apply(Math, Yvalues);
 var yMin = Math.min.apply(Math, Yvalues);
 var Yrange = [yMin,yMax];//Set range

 var layout  = {
     .......
     .......
    yaxis: {
       range:Yrange //Set range
   },
    yaxis2 : {
        range:Yrange, //Set range
        overlaying:'y' // Set overlaying value
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello MD NASIR... Thank for your help. I inputed my traces in your code 'codepen' but didn't work. Try my traces bellow:

var x = [0.0, 30.0, 45.0, 60.0, 90.0, 120.0, 135.0, 150.0, 180.0];
var y1 = [1.608, 1.3936, 0.9648, 0.60032, 0.08576, -0.71824, -1.1685, -1.5544, -2.0582];
var y2 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0];

Comment: Hi @Pereira, on your problem I edited my answer maybe you get a hints to solve this.Thanks